# HTTP dataset credential error

Tags: azure-data-factory

In Azure Data Factory V2, I created a new http dataset an added a url and basic login details to connect to a https endpoint, when use the the Test Connection the response is "Connection successful"

When i try to "Preview data" it fails, the message from more is

The credential to read http file is invalid. Activity ID:89ae4de1-e6be-46fd-abb9-39360fe5323b.

How do i find out more about this error?

When I try the same url and basic login details in Postman I get back the expected results.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Azure data factory, if basic auth type is specified, the http connector honor basic auth protocol, that means：
* It would send out a request without any credential first
* when the http server return 401 response with correct WWW-Authenticate header, it will continue enclose credential into next http request
So if your http server can't handle the request, you will get unauthorize error.

Postman can do it because postman ignored the first http request and send out the second one directly.

Comment: Thanks i tried in postman and without the basic auth the sever does send back a 401 response. what is the correct WWW-Authenticate: header that should be returned ?

Comment: If I do not own the HTTP endpoint I am calling how do I just make it work?

Answer (score 0):

you can manually add header to your request:
Authorization: Basic ......

If you don't know how to generate it, you can copy it from postman, after passing credentials.
Best,
Pawel